# Unsafe Cipher Mode Your app contains a less secure encryption mode. While Uploading on Play Store

Tags: android, encryption, aes, google-play-console, android-security

While trying to upload the app on Play store it shows  the unsafe cipher error and points towards a encryption function.

I have a function taking input a image and converting it to bitmap and than to bytes and using AES encryption to encrypt the file.

```
override suspend fun encryption(imageView: ImageView, name: String, uid: String, x:Firestore, type : String) {
        val bitmap = (imageView.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
        val height = bitmap.height
        Log.d("height", "${height}")
        val width = bitmap.width
        val real = "$name/$height/$width"
         val query3 = Firebase.firestore.collection("profiles").document(uid)
                query3.update(
                    "pending" , FieldValue.arrayUnion(real),
                    type, FieldValue.arrayRemove(name),"isverified_verqreq","falset"
                ).addOnCompleteListener {
                        x.middle()

                        val size = bitmap.rowBytes * bitmap.height
                        val byteBuffer: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size)


                        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer)
                        val byteArray = byteBuffer.array()
                        val storageRef3 =
                            FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("/image/$uid/key/")
                        val key = File.createTempFile("temp", ".txt")
                        storageRef3!!.getFile(key)
                            .addOnSuccessListener {
                                x.middle2()
                                val key2 = key.readBytes()
                                val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
                                val keySpec = SecretKeySpec(key2, "AES")
                                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec)
                                val z = cipher.doFinal(byteArray)
                                val file = File.createTempFile(name, null)
                                file.writeBytes(z)
                                val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                                    .getReference("/image/$uid/$name/")
                                storageReference.putFile(Uri.fromFile(file))
                                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                                        x.sucess(name)


                                    }
                                    .addOnFailureListener {
                                        x.failure()
                                    }
                            }
                    }






            }
```

This code works perfectly fine, it encrypts the image and stores it in firebase.
However Google play store is rasing concernds here claiming unsafe cipher.
I have tried to replayce get instance with

```
val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
```

However If I do this the functionality gets effect and image is not able decrypt.
How should I solve this issue?

Comment: If only the algorithm is specified when instantiating the cipher object, i.e. `Cipher.getInstance("AES")`, provider-dependent values are used for mode and padding. For example, for the SunJCE provider, AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding. ECB is insecure, so no wonder this is complained about.

Comment: GCM, unlike ECB, uses an IV that can be generated explicitly or implicitly and that must be passed to the decrypting side (since it is required for decryption). This IV handling is missing in the code. Also, GCM uses an authentication tag (which is handled implicitly with Java/Android). There are many posts on SO about implementing GCM for Java/Android.

Comment: Note that the IV for GCM has to be never reused, otherwise you can simply break the decryption. So make sure the IV has at least 96 bit, is generated by `SecureRandom` and is never used twice.

Comment: You can find sample GCM implementation for Android for example here https://levelup.gitconnected.com/doing-aes-gcm-in-android-adventures-in-the-field-72617401269d